How to sample a vector $v_2$ with a given euclidean distance and given angle to a reference vector $v_1$ in $\Bbb R^N$
I am trying to sample a vector $v_2$ relative to a reference vector $v_1$. I want to impose its euclidean distance to $v_1$ to be $euc\_dist$ and its angle with $v_1$ to be $\theta$.
An easy way to get the euclidean distance is to sample a direction randomly over the $N$-sphere, scaling the unit norm vector in that direction by $euc\_dist$ and adding the resulting vector to $v_1$. This guarantees $d(v_1,v_2)=euc\_dist$.
However, I don't understand how to introduce the angle constraint without breaking the distance constraint.
Any ideas?
An easier but related problem I'm also stuck with: How to sample $v_2$ constrained to $d(v_1,v_2)=euc\_dist$ with any angle but making sure $\|v_2\|\le\max\_norm$, where $\max\_norm$ is a given norm.
Any insights appreciated!

For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., here, here, here and here.

The set of all vectors at an angle of $\theta$ to $v_1$ form a cone (of dimension $n-1$) with $0$ as the apex. The set of all vectors at a distance $d$ from $v_1$ form an $(n-1)$-sphere about $v_1$. Depending on the sizes of the norm of $v_1$ and $\theta$, the cone and sphere may or may not intersect. When they do not, there are no vectors satisfying your conditions. If they do, the intersection will consist of two parallel $n-2$-spheres ("circles"), which overlap in the extreme case. You can sample these circles randomly, then back out to the original space.
